# set Title for popup in android

Tags: java, android

I want to build application in which I've search button when I clicked on this I get popup where I can search for student name.
I created all of this but I want to set Title for this dialog like "search for student by name"
this is my code

```
public class pop_up extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,container,false);
        Button btn_search = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        Button btn_close = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        TextView result = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_found);
        EditText text = view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn_search.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_close.setOnClickListener(this);
        getDialog().setTitle("Search for Student by Name");
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {...}
}
```

and this is code in MainActivity

```
final FragmentTransaction fragment = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
final pop_up pop = new pop_up();
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_student);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          pop.show(fragment,null);
     }
});
```

Dialog appears but without title, so How can I set Title for it ?

Answer (score 0):

you are crating dialog on completely  wrong way

at first you should use onCreateDiolog insted of onCreatView

you should call AlertDialog.Builder to make dialog

read this doc to know how to use dialogs:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#java

i have project that have bunch of dialog i leave a link if you want more example:
https://github.com/ErfanDP/Erfan_Delavari_HW13_Maktab36